# How to disable android phone's display?

Tags: screen

Hi im looking for method to disable my android phones display running on pie. I don't want to use tap to sleep, power button or simulate that option but I want to simply disable display completely and then turn it back on when I need it. I have rooted my phone already.

Example: I want to watch a YouTube video with only audio. So if I disable the display it can save my battery but pressing power button stops the buffering.

it's just an example for what I want to do this. I don't want it. I'm aware of youtube vanced..

Comment: Do you want to hear only a limited number of YouTube videos I would instead download and convert them to an audio track (using e.g. ClipGrab for PC). This would also save the power to decode the video.

Comment: I do not want it for youtube video. It's just an example of what I mean by disabling display panel and not pressing power button. Thanks for you reply btw.

Comment: Check your Wifi settings, usually when the screen goes off Wifi will be automatically disabled. This may be the reason for the "stops buffering".

Comment: I'm sorry maybe due to my English I am not able to convey what I want. I want to disable the display panel and nothing else. 'YouTube' was an example. All I want is to disable my display panel.

Comment: What you want is now clear, however Android is not designed to only switch off the display. Doing so changes the system state at various places and therefore can affect Wifi and other power saving features. AFAIK the power button simply switches off the display, the "unwanted rest" happens automatically because the display goes off, not because you pressed the power button.

Comment: You may try some stuff from my question, which is somewhat similar. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/204305/how-to-make-an-app-behave-the-same-way-with-screen-off-as-with-screen-on

Comment: Thanks @mnd. it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mnd I found solution for the problem.
The following app works smoothly. It disables only display

https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-screen-backlight-off-xda-exclusive-t3037380

Thanks stackexchange family.
Source: [How to make an app behave the same way with screen off, as with screen on?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/204305/how-to-make-an-app-behave-the-same-way-with-screen-off-as-with-screen-on)